# Nonlinear Mixed Complementarity Problem That I Cannot Solve

Tags: path, nonlinear-optimization, mcpl

I am working on a problem inspired by the model presented in D'Aertrycke, Ehrenmann, Ralph & Smeers (2017) "Risk trading in capacity equilibrium models," specifically section 3.3.1. The model involves a single producer who aims to determine the optimal generation capacity x to maximize profitability, considering the variability in energy demand Q_w across different scenarios w.

The original problem is formulated as follows:

Minimize: Ix + τEΘ[CY_w - A_wQ_w + (B/2) Q_w^2]
Subject to:
Q_w = Y_w
0 <= Y_w <= x

Here:

- x: Generation capacity decided in the initial phase.
- Q_w: Energy demand in scenario w during the production phase.
- Y_w: Energy produced in scenario w during the production phase.
- I: Annual capital expenditure (90).
- τ (Tau): Total hours in a year (8760).
- C: Operational cost (60).
- A_w: Coefficient varying depending on scenario w ([300, 350, 400, 450, 500]).
- B: Constant (1).
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QbmV.png)

To formulate the problem as a Mixed Complementarity Problem (MCP), I started by simplifying the original problem, replacing the variable Y_w with Q_w due to their equality. This led to a reduction in the number of variables and constraints. The simplified Lagrangian function is:

L(x, Q, μ_w) = Ix + τEΘ[CQ_w - A_wQ_w + (B/2) Q_w^2] - μ_w (x - Q_w)

The MCP formulation includes the following components:

- Decision variables: x (generation capacity) and Q_w (energy demand in scenario w).
- Primal constraints: x - Q_w >= 0 for each scenario w.
- Complementary slackness conditions: μ_w (x - Q_w) = 0, with associated Lagrange multipliers μ_w for each scenario w.
- KKT conditions: I - μ_w = 0 and τEΘ[C - A_w + BQ_w] - μ_w = 0.

I attempted to implement and solve this MCP using Julia and the PATHSolver package, but I haven't reached the expected results. I am questioning whether I have accurately transformed the problem into an MCP and am seeking insights, suggestions, or recommendations on whether the formulation is correct, or if there are alternative approaches, solvers, or methodologies that might be more suitable for solving this type of nonlinear MCP.